# How do you open this tab/Menu

Tags: mesh

Does anyone know what the hotkeys for this menu this?

[image]

Comment: F3 is the key that brings up the search menu

Comment: Im trying to find Recalculate Normals. Search Bar wont show it.

Comment: You have to be in edit mode or it won't show up.

Comment: Yeah. Just found out that. Im trying to find Recalculate Normals. But its showing Recalculate Inside or Out.

Comment: which release of blender? In 2.93.6 Recalculate Normals is just above Recalculate Outside

Comment: Just use SHiFT-N and then check or uncheck the 'Inside' checkbox on the setting panel on the bottom-left of the window.